# How can I transfer pictures from a USB flash drive with the Camera Connection Kit?

Tags: ipad, usb, photos, file-transfer

I would like to transfer a bunch of photos onto my iPad without syncing through iTunes.

I had the idea of using a USB flash drive and the Camera Connection Kit, but simply dumping the pictures into the root directory of the drive doesn't work; the iPad says that there are no photos.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by imitating the folder structure of a camera's memory card.

First, find a flash drive that's compatible with the Camera Connection Kit (i.e. doesn't draw more than 100 mA).

Create a directory in the root of the USB drive named `DCIM`. Inside `DCIM` create a directory that has **exactly** 8 characters. Put your picture/video files inside this directory, ensuring that they have an 8.3 pattern filename (e.g. `somepics.jpg`).

You'll end up with a directory structure that looks like this:

```
USB drive root
  -\DCIM
    -\FAKECAM1
      -\pict0001.jpg
      -\pict0002.jpg
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect the ipad usb cord to your Ipad and  computer, get a flash drive, connect as well to your computer. Go to "my computer- Your ipad device should be seen. Open it as you would a file. DCIM file - copy file, go to USB drive, open and then paste DCIM file. Finito...